# Mongodb text search , filter on columns

Tags: mongodb

Running mongo 2.4 RC and experimenting with text search feature

How can I filter the text search command further on other columns values ?

```
 db.Wall.runCommand("text", { search : "Bob"});
```

Comment: Is `filter` (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/limit-number-of-items-scanned-for-text-search/) what you're looking for?

Comment: yep can you post this as answer so I can mark it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's documented [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/limit-number-of-items-scanned-for-text-search/).

As the document shows, you'd add a `filter`:

```
db.inventory.runCommand( "text", {
    search: "Bob",
    filter: { "FavoriteRoom" : "kitchen" }
})
```

Assuming you had a document like:

```
{
    "FavoriteRoom": "kitchen",
    "BlockOfText" : "Bob said he'd like to go out for dinner less often."
}
```

For better performance, you would add an index:

```
db.inventory.ensureIndex({
                        "FavoriteRoom": 1,
                        "BlockOfText": "text"
                      })
```